# Will a Content-Security-Policy with no default-src allow malicious assets?

Tags: content-security-policy

So I have a video on S3 that I want to display to my users.

I have set my CSP to be:

> media-src https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

My question is, because the CSP works at the domain level and S3 buckets are at a folder level I am unsure of whether or not a maliciously loaded JavaScript file that also originates from https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com, but from a different bucket would also be allowed by this CSP?

*edit:* If this is not secure, is there a way to achieve only allowing media from S3 without having to whitelist all other sources of assets?

Comment: I don’t understand the question in your edit. CSP is essentially a whitelist by nature. If you ONLY want to allow source XYZ, why do you think you need to whitelist anything other than XYZ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/
You can use:
https://bucket-name.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

That way only your bucket will be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

“Because the CSP works at the domain level...” — Your premise is incorrect. You can set a CSP source to a directory in the domain, not just the domain — e.g. https://www.example.com/mydir/

Also, media-src will not permit a JavaScript. That’s script-src.  Yes, you should probably set a default-src. (Usually ‘self’ or ‘none’)